# Dynamic member data using unique_ptr and returning data

Tags: c++, oop, smart-pointers

I want to use unique_ptr to dynamically allocate some member array data in my class (please don't comment about vectors or arrays).  I understand how to create my arrays but I am wondering about returning them with `getter` functions.  I want my class to keep ownership of this array and like the memory handling of smart pointers but also need to use the objects data.  This is what I have so far (the .hpp file has the prototype etc. and this is just a minimal snippet for showing code design):

```
 Grid::Grid(std::unique_ptr<Quadrature_Lobatto> a_lobattoQuad,
                               const unsigned int &a_Nbas) { 
  m_Nbas = a_Nbas;
  m_points = std::make_unique<std::complex<double>[]>(m_Nbas);

/* Code that fills in my_points with data */

}

/// Getter for points.
std::complex<double> *FEMDVR::getPoints() const { return m_points.get(); }
```

This code works and I know if I now have `auto tmp = grid.getPoints();` and then change tmp that would also change m_points inside of my grid class and that is not good design behavior.  One way to work around this is to never save it as a variable and just access the elements like `grid.getPoints()[i]`, I suppose.

I am wondering what is a good design for this?  Again, I would like to have dynamically allocated member data and the memory handled with uniqe_ptr.  And if that is the case, how do you work with that object's data later?  What is the best practice here?  Is the best practice really to use std::vector?

Comment: If you don't want anything outside the class to modify its value, don't return mutable pointers/references to the data from any member functions.

Comment: One way you can do it is instead of returning the reference to the array, receive a function that does some operation with the array. This way you don't expose the object. Of course, what the function does and what params receive will depend on what do you need to do.
Another way is to return an iterator instead https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterators-c-stl/

Comment: Here's an example on the former: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: Okay, I will need to digest this.  Is the best practice to use std::vector here?  I think it would do RVO too.

Comment: Couldn't make the return value of `getPoints()` `const` to prevent modification outside the class?
`const std::complex<double> *FEMDVR::getPoints() const { return m_points.get() }`

Comment: Generally, I would consider it to be a better design to have a function `std::complex<double> getPoint(int index) const { return m_points.get()[index]; }`.

Comment: It is **not a good design to separate data and size**. If you want to return a whole container, then return it by reference (`const std::vector<std::complex<double>> &getPoints() const`). Add a non-const overload if desired.

Comment: For most application, the performance difference would be negligible and you should  favor design that best fit your need (hiding details or easy data iterating).

Comment: @zstreet If `m_points` is visible in the header file (i.e. not PIMPL'd), you can define accessor fns (`inline std::complex<double> &getPoint(size_t i);` and `inline std::complex<double> getPoint(size_t i) const;`. If there is no reason for clients to get all the points, you can remove the `getPoints` fn.

Comment: @zstreet See [here](https://onlinegdb.com/rkcJBgxeD)